# How to enable href link on second click of list-group-item in Bootstrap 3.3.6?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

With Bootstrap 3.3.6 and jQuery, I am attempting to enable a list-group-item link to go to a page, only if it's child drop-down list is open/visible.  So on the first click, the drop-down expands.  But if someone clicks the same link after the drop-down is open, they then should go to the href value assigned to that same link.  This is my code so far...

```
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="my-list">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Link 0</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#set01" data-parent="#my-list">
                        <a class="jq-list-link" href="http://google.com">Link 1</a>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down text-color-red pull-right"></span>
                            <ul class="sublinks collapse" id="set01">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#set02" data-parent="#my-list">
                        <a href="http://google.com" class="jq-list-link">Link 2</a>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down text-color-red pull-right"></span>
                            <ul class="sublinks collapse" id="set02">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

The jQuery I am attempting to use is the following...

```
var mtarget = $('.jq-list-link');
if (mtarget.length) {   
    mtarget.click(function(e) {

        if ( mtarget.attr('aria-expanded') == "true") {                    
        console.log('aria true');
        window.location = $(this).href; 
        } else if (mtarget.attr('aria-expanded') == "false") {
        console.log('aria false');
        e.preventDefault();
        } else {
        console.log('aria does not exist');
        e.preventDefault();
        }                                
    });
  }
```

My problem is that on the second click, it doesn't go anywhere. It just closes it's child panel. It thinks that aria-expanded does not exist the whole time. Do I have to use custom jQuery to achieve what I am doing? If so, what am I doing wrong?  I have the project setup on bootply as well - http://www.bootply.com/rhJKRJl7KL

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use === instead of == in your jQuery if statements?

Comment: I just tried it - on every click I get "aria does not exist"

Comment: `console.log(mtarget.attr('aria-expanded'));` brings back `undefined` for me...would explain why it's not getting to the "true" or "false" block

Comment: That is so odd, because that attribute and it's value does load when you do click on the link...easily seen when we inspect the element from developer tools...

Comment: so, I just copied your code verbatim, added jquery and bootstrap cdn tags, and it worked as expected, redirected to google on second click....are you seeing any js errors in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "aria-expanded" attr is appearing on the containing "li", not on the "a" tag. So try:

```
<script>
var mtarget = $('.jq-list-link');
if (mtarget.length) {   
    mtarget.click(function(e) {

        if ( $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded') == "true") {                    
        console.log('aria true');
        window.location = $(this).href; 
        } else if ($(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded') == "false") {
        console.log('aria false');
        e.preventDefault();
        } else {
        console.log('aria does not exist');
        e.preventDefault();
        }                                
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: well, thats because you are using a class query, and its actually matching both elements, so mtarget.parent() is looking at the parents of both links, and since one of them has the attr set to true, its sending you to where you just clicked( because "this" refers to the element that was clicked, not mtarget)

Comment: yep, you solved it the way I was just about to suggest. Edits above.